# Screen shifted down on netbook after creating new xrandr resolution

Tags: xorg, display, xrandr, ubuntu-netbook

Have an older Toshiba nb205 netbook which after switching to Lubuntu from Windows 7 starter ran many years wonderfully. Had not had much reason to use it but resently went back to it, updated software and drivers and discovered that the desktop is larger than the screen and the bottom of the desktop is not visible. It appears that the Intel driver updated it's resolution to 1024x768 (a new MS standard?) while the netbook screen still has the physical limitation of 1024x600.

No problem - create a modeline for 1024x600, add the mode to LVDS1 and the screen display is perfectly sized, BUT, the alignment on the display is adjusted down about 1 inch from the top of the panel with approx an inch of the desktop "off" the display on the bottom. While this is better than the "default" I don't just leave it that way.  Most of what I've found regarding xrandr and similar display issues is referring to external monitors which is not the issue here.  --pos has no effect (which makes sense.)

The modeline which cvt came up with: "1024x600_60.00" 49.00 1024 1072 1168 1312 600 603 613 624 -hsync +vsync.

Because switching modes back and forth resets the origin I have to think that there is something about the modeline that is incorrect, however everything I have tried comes up with a similar modeline calculation. I do not know enough about the various parameters to begin changing numbers so looking for input.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could have changed it back to the correct resolution or was 1024x768 the only option in screen settings? Anyway, wouldn't it be easier now to just do a fresh install of the current Lubuntu?

Comment: OK - follow-up to my own question.  I've been thinking about this incorrectly the 1024x768 mode works fine - it just thinks it has more monitor to work with than it does.  So like a few folks trying to get around broken flat panels xrandr --fb 1024x600 should tell the system to just use the portion that actually displays.  Does complain a little, but also seems to work for the most part.

Comment: Just a last note - I suspect this could be an issue for all of the small screen toshiba netbooks - if you are running Lubuntu and the task bar is off the screen on the bottom remember terminal lxpanelctl config and move it all to the top of the desktop.  Thanks for the idea MichaelBay.